# Why does export CC=/usr/bin/gcc not change the environment variable

Tags: gcc, environment-variables, cygwin-64

I'm using a bash shell in Cygwin.  CC is set to a mingw compiler.

```
$ env | grep CC
CC=x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe
```

I want to change it to /usr/bin/gcc.

```
$ export CC=/usr/bin/gcc
$ env | grep CC
CC=x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe
```

I noticed that in my ~/.bashrc file there is a line

```
set CC=x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe
```

But even when I change that line to /usr/bin/gcc, CC is still set to the mingw compiler.